# Feeding large pandas dataframe into Tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, bigdata

I am trying to use data from a Pandas dataframe to feed into a Tensorflow pipeline. I tried to do this:

```
training_dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
         tf.cast(df[df.columns[:-1]].values, tf.float32),
         tf.cast(df[df.columns[-1]].values, tf.int32))))
```

where `df` is my dataframe. However it is very large and I got this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB.
```

Should I split the dataframe and create several tensor datasets, and would that even work? What is the best way to approach this? I thought about feeding the data into `feed_dict`, but I couldnt figure out how to go about it.

Comment: If you say that you couldn't figure how to go about `feed_dict` could you post the code you wrote so far? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to manually split your dataframe. You can use `tf.placeholder` to avoid hitting 2GB graphdef limit. Create numpy arrays from dataframe using `DataFrame.values` Take a look at this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays